# ADF Faces multiple file upload

Tags: java, file-upload, oracle-adf

I am trying to create multiple file upload by using multiple af:inputFile component. Here is my xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
  <f:view>
    <af:document id="d1" title="Home">
      <af:form id="f1" usesUpload="true">
        <af:commandButton text="Add" immediate="true"
                          actionListener="#{viewScope.massUpload.add}"
                          id="cb2"/>
        <af:panelGroupLayout layout="vertical" id="pgl1" partialTriggers="cb1">
          <af:iterator value="#{viewScope.massUpload.fileComponents}" var="fileComponent"
                       id="i1" varStatus="status">
            <af:inputFile binding="#{fileComponent}" id="if1"
                          value="#{viewScope.massUpload.files[status.index]}"/>
          </af:iterator>
          <af:commandButton text="Upload"
                            actionListener="#{viewScope.massUpload.upload}"
                            id="cb1"/>
        </af:panelGroupLayout>
      </af:form>
    </af:document>
  </f:view>
</jsp:root>
```

and this is the managed bean:

```
package com.edfx.massupload.bean;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import oracle.adf.view.rich.component.rich.input.RichInputFile;

import oracle.stellent.ridc.IdcClientException;

import org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.model.UploadedFile;


public class MassUploadBean {
    private List<RichInputFile> fileComponents = new ArrayList<RichInputFile>();
    private List<UploadedFile> files = new ArrayList<UploadedFile>();

    public MassUploadBean() {
        super();        
    }

    public void add(ActionEvent event) {   
        fileComponents.add(new RichInputFile());
        files.add(null);
    }

    public void upload(ActionEvent event) throws IdcClientException {
        for(UploadedFile file : files) {
            System.out.println(file.getFilename());
        }
    }

    public void setFiles(List<UploadedFile> files) {
        this.files = files;
    }

    public List<UploadedFile> getFiles() {
        return files;
    }

    public void setFileComponents(List<RichInputFile> fileComponents) {
        this.fileComponents = fileComponents;
    }

    public List<RichInputFile> getFileComponents() {
        return fileComponents;
    }
}
```

The problems that I am facing are:

1. I have clicked on the Add button; a new file upload component added to the page; I browse a file; Again clicked on the Add button; Another file upload component added and the first file upload get submitted (but it is having a border, or something similar); I browse file from the second file upload; Again click on Add button; now the first file upload get cleared (reset) and the second file upload get submitted;
2. Whenever I clicked on the Add button the file get uploaded. Why? How to resist it? I have tried by setting atoSubmit="false" but no luck. Also tried to put the iterator, file uploader and the Upload button inside af:subForm
3. My requirement is to Upload the file when the upload button is clicked, not before.

Am I doing something wrong? Any pointer would be very helpful.

Comment: Did you see: http://docs.oracle.com/html/E18745_01/devguide/fileUpload.html?

Comment: @DaveJarvis I have seen the documentation. Why is there any differences? Are you pointing the `valueChangeListener`? I cannot use the `autoSubmit` property.

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using IdcClientException which tells me you're uploading into UCM.  If you're also using WebCenter then you might be able to use the out of the box Upload task flow that comes with WebCenter Portal: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29597_01/webcenter.1111/e25595/jpsdg_content_jsfpg.htm#autoId18

As of PS5 that task flow will do multifile upload for you.

Answer (score 1):

THe later versions of ADF should help with bulk upload:
 http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_inputFile.html

Turn on displayMode and maximumFiles (see also uploadType).